# Is there a way to redirect to a default url hash with React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, url-routing, react-router-dom, browser-history

I am using React Router 5.

I have a path `/item/:id`. When I navigate to this path I want to be able to load the page with a default hash identifier. `i.e. /item/:id#123`

For more context I have a list of steps on my page associated with an item. Every time a user selects a different step, the hash changes accordingly like so:

```
step 1 -> /item/123#1
step 2 -> /item/123#2
step 3 -> /item/123#3
```

Here's a rough implementation of my component code:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import steps from './steps'

const ItemPage = ({ history, location }) => {
  const { hash, pathname } = location
  const changeURLhash = idx => {
    history.push({ pathname: pathname, hash: idx.toString() })
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {steps.map(step => (
        <li key={i} onClick={changeURLhash}>
          {step.title}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

I am able to change the hash after selecting a step but on initial page load when nothing has been clicked yet there is no hash in the url path. I need to change this because step 1 is selected by default on page load.

What would be the best way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm assuming this is for a scenario where the user completes something on the form, leaves then comes back, you would want there progress to be saved some how right?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Exactly. A user should be able to copy and paste that link on a different browser and show the same state for which step is currently active. Just need that initial default hash selection.

Comment: I seee. But how would the data from the previous steps be preserved in this case?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo I see what you mean. The state of the steps is persisted as a user types which preserves the data. But the only thing I'm tracking with the hash identifier is which step is highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve this by using history.replace in a useEffect hook.

When the page loads and there is no hash identifier in the url, I replace the current path in the history stack with a new path containing a default hash

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!hash) history.replace({ pathname: pathname, hash: '0' })
}, [hash, history, pathname])
```

Using replace instead of push here eliminates the unnecessary extra entry that gets added to the history stack.

Comment: can you please elaborate whether you are using `window.history ` or `let history = useHistory()`

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to see your code, it's difficult to cater an exact solution to your problem. However, I've created a sandbox for you to demonstrate how you might do this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-sinoussi-5eomb

Essentially, your `Item` component needs a combination of `useState` and `useEffect`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Item = ({ steps }) => {
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    const path = window.location.href;
    const step =
      path.indexOf("#") !== -1 ? path.slice(path.indexOf("#") + 1) : "";
    if (step) {
      setCurrentStep(step);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleOnClick = step => {
    setCurrentStep(step);
  };

  const createSteps = () => {
    return steps.map((step, index) => {
      return (
        <div
          className={step == currentStep ? "currentStep" : "step"}
          key={index}
          onClick={() => handleOnClick(step)}
        >
          <h4>Step: {step}</h4>
          <input />
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
  return <div>{createSteps()}</div>;
};

export default Item;
```

You have an state to keep track of the current step. And a mark-up creator function to apply the highlighted class to the active item. Then in the `useEffect()` you would just extract the step number (character after the #) and set your state to that value. That will re-render the component, and your mark-up creator will apply the class to that step.

Comment: I've tried doing this but the problem with this is the url appends the hash after the component mounts and creates an unnecessary extra entry in the history stack. So at first the url will look like /item/123 then after a moment it turns into /item/123#0. To go back, the user would have to click twice. Hope that makes sense. Looking for a more optimal way to set that default #0 upon first visit.